# junit5 springbootApp testing custom properties without SpringBootTest or WebMvcTest

Tags: spring-boot

I have custom property defined like this:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bank.alior")
@Validated
@Data
public class CustomProperties {

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private String clientSecret;
}
```

i would like to use CustomProperties bean in tests. I know that i can use @SpringBootTest (But this load whole springboot app context) or  @WebMvcTest - but this also loads to much - for example security context. I would like simply only those properties value.

My test should look like this

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Import(CustomProperties.class)
//something what is missing
public class SomeTest{

@Autowired
CustomProperties prop;

@Test
public void ClientSecretFromPropertyIsNotNull(){
assertTrue(prop.getClientSecret()!=null)
}
}
```

but in this setup this test fails, If I add `SpringBootTest` or `WebMvcTest` annotation it will pass.

Comment: This is a specific Sprig boot feature you want to test without spring boot?

Comment: I want to test only this, I would like to import only properties, in the same way, i can do when i specify `controllers` in `@WebMvcTest` when i can only load controllers which i specify, and only this

Comment: And you want to test what? You are basically testing the functioning of Spring Boot nothing from your own code.